# iMac Finder leaves whitespace after file deletion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, finder, imac

I'm a new Mac user with OS X Lion.  When deleting items in finder, I'm surprised that, unlike Windows, the computer doesn't automatically clean up the white space created by my deletion.  So, in a file with many photos, there is a lot of white space between the remaining photos.  How can I correct this without manually moving the photos?

Comment: Windows Explorer has the same feature. It is the "Autoarrange Icons" menu item in the View menu of Windows Explorer. I believe that in Finder you will find the similar thing

Answer (score 1):

#### Use a view that does it automatically

Only the *Icon view* leaves empty space when removing items. *List view* and *Column view* in Finder don't leave space after removing some items. You can switch views in the *View* menu.

#### Arrange items

Select *View » Arrange By » (anything)* to group items by a specific criterion. It will automatically reorder items when some are removed. The desktop cannot be arranged.

#### Sort items

You can keep items sorted by keeping <kbd>Option</kbd> pressed, and then selecting *View » Sort By » (anything)*.

#### Clean up

If you don't want Finder to keep a folder's contents tidy, you can manually invoke *View » Clean Up By » (anything)* after you're done.